# How do I go about batch-optimizing image files with a script?

Tags: windows, images, batch-file

I'm using [OptiPNG](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/) for a large amount of PNGs I need to optimize. I can get it to run with a batch script where the application *and* image are in one folder together.

`start.bat` contains:

```
start _OPNG.exe *.png -zc9 -zm9 -zs3 -f0-5 -nc -strip "all"
```

However, let's say I have a folder in `d:\images` with `1.png` through `10.png`, then I've got a sub-folder `d:\images\sub1` with `1sub.png` through `10sub.png`.

The app is located in, let's say, `f:\OptiPNG\optipng.exe`.

I want a batch file where I have to manually edit just the location of the image folder I want to optimize. The batch file should take into account all PNGs in that folder and its subfolders.

Anybody able to help me out?

Comment: I've never used OptiPNG before. Is it better than Pngcrush?

Comment: No clue. Don't know Pngcrush.

Comment: I checked out PNGCrush, it's indeed better! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! As it turns out OptiPNG is a fork of PNGCrush.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
@echo off
echo.
set apppath="F:\OptiPNG\OptiPNG.exe"
if [%1]==[] echo Usage: %0 "PNG Dir" && echo. && echo Error: Invalid parameters && goto :EOF
if not exist %1 echo Usage: %0 "PNG Dir" && echo. && echo Error: Invalid directory "%~1" && goto :EOF
%apppath% "%~1\*.png" -zc9 -zm9 -zs3 -f0-5 -nc -strip "all"
for /d /r "%~1" %%a in (*.*) do %apppath% "%%~a\*.png" -zc9 -zm9 -zs3 -f0-5 -nc -strip "all"
```

Comment: Just in case it's not clear, save it as something like **Optimise.bat**, then call with `Optimise "D:\Images"` to optimise all PNGs in the specified dir and *all* its sub-dirs.

Comment: Much obliged!!!

Comment: If I could bother you again, Karan. Could you do another batch file, but this time with Pngcrush as application? Don't worry much about the -xyz commands, these I'll look up myself in Pngcrus and add accordingly to the batch file! Thanks!

Comment: I'm not on my PC right now so can't confirm, but IIRC pngcrush should accept wildcards like \*.png just as optipng does. In that case all you need to do is modify *apppath* to point to pngcrush.exe, and of course ensure you're using parameters appropriate to the program.

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work. PNGCrush has different commands that I apparently am too dumb to incorporate. I can read the "usage" section when executing pngcrush.exe but that's...really...descriptive...

Comment: pngcrush.exe's -e and -d options will allow you to use wildcards. Do some test runs with them; shouldn't be too hard to figure out.

Comment: I give up, I'm too stupid for this stuff. Thanks for the help with OptiPNG. Appreciate it.

Comment: I don't want to open another topic, so I'll bother you again Karan. Could you please take a look at PNGCrush and edit your post with another addition for PNGCrush pretty please?

Comment: Some updates: I was using an old version of pngcrush that had wildcard (*.png) support, but looks like this has been broken for quite some time now. The developer has been informed and is looking into it, but meanwhile OptiPNG is the better solution.